# Are there any security risks to store "id_token" of openId in session storage of client browser

Tags: security, openid

Identity provider and authorization endpoint are in the same server as a authorization server: "auth-server".

There multiple resource providers in **each own resource servers**: "res-server1, res-server2, ...."

**First**,  request id_token from "auth-server" and and store the id_token in session storage of client browser. This is just an "authorization code flow" which is defined in RFC 6749

[image]

The access token from auth-server can only used by auth-server, but not by other res-servers.

**Second**, request "res access token" from "res-server" via "id_token".

**Third**, request "res api" with "res access token".

Or just use "id_token" as access token.

I would like to know are there any security risks to store id_token in session storage of client browser, and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that it is on the client side and no matter what you do it will always remain insecure. Would suggest to have an intermediate server side layer which tracks the ID Token for a particular client.